# \dotfill inside \multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

`\dotfill` does not seem to display anything when placed inside `\multirow` as shown below.
I'm trying to display the dots after "Pongidae, divisé en" on the same line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigdelim}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{5.5cm}p{0.01cm}p{4.5cm}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Taxons de Simpson} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Taxons de Goodman} \\
Primates, inchangé\dotfill & & Primates \\
Prosimii, divisé en\dotfill &  & Strepsirhini \\
Anthropoidea, inchangé\dotfill &  & Tarsioidea \\
Ceboidea, inchangé\dotfill &  & Anthropoidea \\
Cercopithecoidea, inchangé\dotfill &  & Platyrrhini (Ceboidea) \\
Hominoidea, inchangé\dotfill &  & Hominoidea \\
\multirow{3}{*}{*Pongidae, divisé en\dotfill} & \rdelim\{{3}{} & Hylobatidae \\
 &  & Ponginae \\
 &  & Homininae (en partie: Pan) \\
\multirow{2}{*}{*Ponginae, divisé en\dotfill} & \rdelim\{{2}{} & Ponginae \\
 &  & Homininae (en partie: Pan) \\
Hylobatinae, inchangé\dotfill &  & Hylobatidae \\
Hominidae, inchangé\dotfill &  & \textit{Homo} \\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{*Taxon à la composition modifiée (composantes)} \\
 &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! How  is the `\rdelim` command defined?

Comment: It is best if you give a complete, working examples, with `\documentclass`, `\usepackage` etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have edited the original question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\multirow{n}{*}` uses the 'natural width' of its text parameter, i.e. the smallest amount that is necessary. Then no space will be left for the `\dotfill`. Instead use `{=}` as width specification which takes the width of the column definition. Also your `\rdelim` is wrong, because it needs a width specification, which in this case can be `*` or `=`.

Here is the working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigdelim}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{5.5cm}p{0.01cm}p{4.5cm}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Taxons de Simpson} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Taxons de Goodman} \\
Primates, inchangé\dotfill & & Primates \\
Prosimii, divisé en\dotfill &  & Strepsirhini \\
Anthropoidea, inchangé\dotfill &  & Tarsioidea \\
Ceboidea, inchangé\dotfill &  & Anthropoidea \\
Cercopithecoidea, inchangé\dotfill &  & Platyrrhini (Ceboidea) \\
Hominoidea, inchangé\dotfill &  & Hominoidea \\
\multirow{3}{=}{*Pongidae, divisé en\dotfill} & \rdelim\{{3}{*} & Hylobatidae \\
 &  & Ponginae \\
 &  & Homininae (en partie: Pan) \\
\multirow{2}{=}{*Ponginae, divisé en\dotfill} & \rdelim\{{2}{*} & Ponginae \\
 &  & Homininae (en partie: Pan) \\
Hylobatinae, inchangé\dotfill &  & Hylobatidae \\
Hominidae, inchangé\dotfill &  & \textit{Homo} \\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{*Taxon à la composition modifiée (composantes)} \\
 &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]